# simple html dom parser find text

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

In my case page have multiple `table` with same class so I find value with help of `tr, td and plaintext`.

**PHP Part:**

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');
$eles = $html->find('.info-tab');
foreach($eles as $e) {
    if(strpos($e->find('tr',0)->plaintext, "Information about the manufacturer and the model." ) ) {
    $value1 = $e->find('td',1)->plaintext;
    }

    if(strpos($e->find('tr',1)->plaintext, "Information about the manufacturer and the model." ) ) {
    $value2 = $e->find('td',1)->plaintext;
    }
}
echo $value1;
echo $value2;
```

**Web Page**

```
// Here's will be many other "Table" with diffrent text but class & ID are same...

<table class="info-tab">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Information about the manufacturer and the model.</td>
            <td>1000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dummy text</td>
            <td>dummy text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

// Here's will be many other "Table" with diffrent text but class & ID are same...

<table class="info-tab">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>dummy text</td>
            <td>dummy text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Information about the manufacturer and the model.</td>
            <td>3000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dummy text</td>
            <td>dummy text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

// Here's will be many other "Table" with diffrent text but class & ID are same...
```

Page have multiple table 20 plus, only two table have this text so I want to copy them.

**How can I find these two values?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate tables and for each table, iterate the rows:

```
$token = "Information about the manufacturer and the model.";
$tables = $html->find('.info-tab');
$values = [];
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    foreach ($table->find('tr') as $row) {
        if (strpos($row->find('td', 0)->plaintext, $token) !== false) {
            $values [] = $row->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($values);
```

Your code doesn't work becuase `$e->find('td', 1)` is always the second td of the first row in the table (and it doesn't consider the selected row 0 or 1).

Comment: Nope, it stores all such values in an array, so the output for your provided html would be an array of two elements.

Comment: Thanks its working. Can I store these values into two different variable?

Comment: Of course you can do that but I guess you don't actually need. In the end this code, your $value1 would be $values[0] and $value2 would $values[1]. So, can easily use this array instead of your two variables.

Comment: Yes, Thanks again for solution